# Eureka instances are showing in available

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka

Hi i have 3 instances of Eureka Server. I made the peer connection between these 3 instances by registering them to each other as a client.
Initially my all instances are up and are showing in available-replicas.
But when i down the other two instances yet they are showing in available-replicas.
Please help me with the configuration.

[image: Eureka dashboard]

Properties

```
peer1-
  server.port=7555
    eureka.instance.hostname=instance01
    spring.application.name=EurekaServerCluster
    eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone:http://instance02:7555/eureka/,http://instance03:7555/eureka/
    eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
    eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
    eureka.client.healthcheck.enabled=true
    eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=false

 peer2-
  server.port=7555
    eureka.instance.hostname=instance02
    spring.application.name=EurekaServerCluster
    eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone:http://instance01:7555/eureka/,http://instance03:7555/eureka/
    eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
    eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
    eureka.client.healthcheck.enabled=true
    eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=false

peer3-
  server.port=7555
    eureka.instance.hostname=instance03
    spring.application.name=EurekaServerCluster
    eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone:http://instance01:7555/eureka/,http://instance02:7555/eureka/
    eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
    eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
    eureka.client.healthcheck.enabled=true
    eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=false
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens due to self preservation mode. Read [here](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Server-Self-Preservation-Mode)

You can turn off the mode by putting below property.

```
eureka.server.enableSelfPreservation: false
```